# GA Funnel Visualization is showing an increase in entrances late in funnel

Tags: google-analytics, conversions, goal-tracking

My funnel has never shown "entrances" past the enrollment stage of the funnel until I started running an A/B test through visual website optimizer in that step. Now "entrance" shows up about in almost every later step in process. equals to roughly 5% of over all entries. (important b/c it is not equal to the amount that are being show variation B at 50%) Also the test is not a split URL test so it is not taking people off of the page. (it is javascript based).

When I pause test it disappears. The site is in sitecore if that helps at all too. Also, the timed session in the funnel is set at a normal 30 mins and has not changed before or after test so I have ruled that out as well.

I can't figure out why it is happening. Any ideas would be helpful!